# CodeIgniter- Message: Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a view that shows me the data from the database.

but the result is

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: mentee/index.php

UserModel.php

```
<?php

class UserModel extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function userProfile($nim){
        $this->db->where('userNIM',$nim);
        $query= $this->db->get('msuser');
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

MainController.php

```
public function indexMentee()
    {
        $this->load->model('UserModel');
        $userID=$this->session->userdata("userNIM");
        $data['data'] = $this->UserModel->userProfile($userID);
        $this->load->view('mentee/index', array('data' => $data));

     }
```

View

```
<?php 
die(var_dump($data));
if(is_array($data)){
    foreach ($data as $profile): 

?>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <h1>Learning Center</h1>
                <hr>    
                <h3> Welcome,<?php echo $profile->userName ?></h3>                                
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Please help me..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `array('data' => $data));` just pass `$data` to the view.

Answer (score 0):

First print session data. If session data present then pass data to view page

```
$data['details'] = $this->UserModel->userProfile($userID);
$this->load->view('mentee/index', $data);
```

And print `print_r($details);` on your view page